# Redim Statement alternative in C#- Code giving errors

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms

I know there is no `Redim` Statement in C#. I had this old code written in VB and I converted it into C# using Telerik Tool. Now the online tool gave some comments when it encountered `Redim` statement. The VB code and the C# code is given below.

```
Public Function ReadMultiCurvedDataFromFile(ByRef filenumber As Short) As ConvexMultiCurveDataType
        Dim i As Short
        Dim OutData As ConvexMultiCurveDataType = InitConvexMultiCurveDataType()
        Try
            With OutData
                FileGet(filenumber, .BlendFactor)
                FileGet(filenumber, .EdgeRadius)
                FileGet(filenumber, .OZShapeFactor)
                FileGet(filenumber, .OZPrismOffset)
                FileGet(filenumber, .NumOzCurves)
                If .NumOzCurves > 0 Then
                    ReDim .OZCurveData(.NumOzCurves - 1)
                    For i = 0 To .NumOzCurves - 1
                        FileGet(filenumber, .OZCurveData(i))
                    Next
                End If
                FileGet(filenumber, .NumLenticularCurves)
                If .NumLenticularCurves > 0 Then
                    ReDim .CurveData(.NumLenticularCurves - 1)
                    For i = 0 To .NumLenticularCurves - 1
                        FileGet(filenumber, .CurveData(i))
                    Next
                End If
            End With
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try
        Return OutData
    End Function
```

**C# code**

```
public static Mold_Power_Suite.Model.ConvexSurfaceStructures.ConvexMultiCurveDataType ReadMultiCurvedDataFromFile(ref short filenumber)
        {
            int filenumber1 = filenumber;
            long i = 0;
            Mold_Power_Suite.Model.ConvexSurfaceStructures.ConvexMultiCurveDataType OutData =ConvexSurfaceStructures. InitConvexMultiCurveDataType();
            try
            {
                var _with30 = OutData;
                FileSystem.FileGet(filenumber,ref _with30.BlendFactor);
                FileSystem.FileGet(filenumber,ref _with30.EdgeRadius);
                FileSystem.FileGet(filenumber,ref _with30.OZShapeFactor);
                FileSystem.FileGet(filenumber, ref _with30.OZPrismOffset);
                FileSystem.FileGet(filenumber,ref _with30.NumOzCurves);

                if (_with30.NumOzCurves > 0)
                {
                    //Array.Resize();
                    // ERROR: Not supported in C#: ReDimStatement

                    for ( i = 0; i <= _with30.NumOzCurves - 1; i++)
                    {

                        FileSystem.FileGet(filenumber1, ref  _with30.OZCurveData[i]); // GETTING MENTIONED ERROR HERE
                    }
                }
                FileSystem.FileGet(filenumber,ref _with30.NumLenticularCurves);
                if (_with30.NumLenticularCurves > 0)
                {
                    // ERROR: Not supported in C#: ReDimStatement

                    for (i = 0; i <= _with30.NumLenticularCurves - 1; i++)
                    {
                        FileSystem.FileGet(filenumber1, ref _with30.CurveData[i]); //GETTING MENTIONED ERROR HERE
                    }
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            }
            return OutData;
        }
```

**OZCurveData** has been defined as

```
 Dim OZCurveData() As ConvexOZCurveDataType
```

and **ConvexOZCurveDataType** as

```
Public Structure ConvexOZCurveDataType
        Dim SphereRadius As Double
        Dim CylRadius As Double
        Dim Diameter As Double
        Dim Addition As Double
    End Structure
```

I am getting error at the mentioned lines. The errors is

> The best overloaded method match for 'Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileSystem.FileGet(int, ref System.DateTime, long)' has some invalid arguments

`Redim` is also an issue.

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/967423/1997232) regarding redim.

Comment: how did you get that background color under redim word ?

Comment: Usage `Array.Resize(ref array, new size);`

Comment: What is the type of `_with30.CurveData[i]`? And the one of `_with30.OZCurveData[i]`?

Comment: public ConvexCurveDataType[] CurveData;     public ConvexOZCurveDataType[] OZCurveData;

Comment: @Apoorv So how is it possible that the VB worked? I mean, also in VB.NET code the datatypes were the same, didn't they? And AFAIK there is no overload of FileGet that accepts `ConvexCurveDataType` or `ConvexOZCurveDataType`

Comment: thats what I dont understand .

Comment: @Apoorv `ConvexCurveDataType` and `ConvexOZCurveDataType` are structure or classes?

Comment: The *exact* VB definition of CurveData (all the way down to the primitive data types it emcompasses) is the essence of your problem (much more relevant than the lines of code you posted). Please include them in your problem statement, don't make the commenters pull this information out one question at the time.

Comment: @MatteoUmili just saw your comment. They are structures.

Comment: `VB.NET` is "permissive", so you are allowed to pass `ByRef` a derived type of the expected one. In our case, in VB `FileGet(Integer, ByRef ValueType)` gets called. `C#` doesn't allow this, so you'll need to create a temporary object of type `ValueType` and assign to it `OZCurveData`/`CurveData`, then pass it to `FileGet` and then assign the value of the temporary object to `OZCurveData`/`CurveData`. Eg:
`ValueType vObj = _with30.OZCurveData[i];
Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileSystem.FileGet(1, ref vObj);
_with30.OZCurveData[i] = (ConvexOZCurveDataType)vObj ;`

Comment: @MatteoUmili it would be great if you could write is as an answer to my question ?

Comment: _with30.OZCurveData = new ConvexOZCurveDataType[_with30.NumOzCurves];  You are wasting your time rewriting this in C#, it does *not* get any better and is quite unnecessary when you can simply add a reference to the assembly.

Comment: @HansPassant sir can you elaborate as an answer to my question ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`VB.NET` is "permissive", so you are allowed to pass `ByRef` a derived type of the expected one. In our case, in VB `FileGet(Integer, ByRef ValueType)` gets called. `C#` doesn't allow this, so you'll need to create a temporary object of type `ValueType` and assign to it `OZCurveData`/`CurveData`, then pass it to `FileGet` and then assign the value of the temporary object to `OZCurveData`/`CurveData`. Eg:

```
ValueType vObj = _with30.OZCurveData[i];
Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileSystem.FileGet(1, ref vObj);
_with30.OZCurveData[i] = (ConvexOZCurveDataType)vObj ;
```

About `Redim`, you can use `Array.Resize` (as @Gaurav Singh Jantwal said):

```
Array.Resize(ref _with30.OZCurveData, _with30.NumOzCurves - 1);
```

Comment: do I need this line _with30.OZCurveData[i] = (ConvexOZCurveDataType)vObj ; ? do I have to put it after FileSystem.FileGet() , inside for loop ?

Comment: Yes, if you don't do that,  `_with30.OZCurveData[i]` value won't change